# How do you say "What is the dragon holding" in french

Tags: traduction

I have tried most of the on-line translators but I don't think they give the right answer. Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean.

If you mean what the dragon is actually holding, like a pearl in [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_dragon#/media/File:Metal_dragon_half_frontal_view.jpg), then you would say "Que tient le dragon ?" or "Qu'est-ce que le dragon tient ?"

However, if you mean a treasure or something that the dragon would be guarding then you would say "Que garde le dragon ?" or "Qu'est-ce que le dragon garde ?"

In both cases, the first sentence is much better than the second.

If you mean something else, let me know in the comments.

Comment: I am impressed that you found a picture of a dragon holding something. It was exactly what I was looking for.